# Wrong object's type after possible return of empty stream

Tags: java, object, lambda, casting, java-stream

I have written following code:

```
Set<Pair<Predicate>> interestingPairs = ...
...
interestingPairs.stream()
                .filter(pair -> pair.getFirst().isNegated() == pair.getSecond().isNegated())
                .flatMap( pair -> findUnification(pair)
                    .map(u -> {
                        Set<String> aVars = pair.getFirst().getAllVariables();
                        Set<String> bVars = pair.getSecond().getAllVariables();
                        if(u.sigma.isEmptyOrVarByVar(aVars) && !u.sigmaPrime.isEmptyOrVarByVar(bVars))
                            return Stream.of(pair.getFirst());
                        if (!u.sigma.isEmptyOrVarByVar(bVars) && u.sigmaPrime.isEmptyOrVarByVar(aVars))
                            return Stream.of(pair.getSecond());
                        return Stream.empty();
                    })
                    .orElse(Stream.empty()))
                .forEach(toRemove -> this.predicates.remove((Predicate)toRemove));
```

I'm using intelliJ IDE. After `flatMap` operation elements of my stream have `Object` type instead of `Predicate`, so in the `foreach` `toRemove` has not desired type. When I change `return Stream.empty()` to `return Stream.<Predicate>empty()`, object's type after `flatMap` is `Predicate`. I would even understand this if not `.orElse(Stream.empty())` where I don't have to add the `<Predicate` implicitly. What's the thing I don't get here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your `Predicate` is your custom non-generic type, not the `java.util.function.Predicate`. Seems that the compiler fails to infer the type of the `.flatMap` argument. You may help it specifying it explicitly:

```
interestingPairs.stream()
            .filter(pair -> pair.getFirst().isNegated() == pair.getSecond().isNegated())
            .<Predicate>flatMap( pair -> findUnification(pair)
            ... and so on
```

To my understanding, current JLS automatic type inference rules do not cover this case, so it's not a compiler bug. You just have to specify type argument explicitly sometimes or extract some complex lambdas to intermediate variables.